# Consolidating Delegate function in functions doesn't make sense

Tags: c#, delegates, pinvoke

I found a opensource code that was a much simpler version of NAudio for my C# application. Which for me is better because all I am looking to do is play a brief sound out of the speakers to test that they are plugged in and working, and I also want to listen to the microphone. The project it self looked ok, but i felt that it could be refactored a bit into smaller chucks. Another thing i found is that the WaveOutBuffer.cs and WaveInBuffer.cs files were remarkably similar. So i started to make a abstract class WaveBuffer. This would have all the similar functions and variables in it that would be passed. One that i am having troubles with is as follows. Another file WaveNative.cs has  delegate in it. I am very new to delegates and Events so i know it has the potential to be very important. but i dont like the way that it is setup to be used. So i'll post what Is in each file and how it is used, then show what i have been trying to get to work. Maybe between all of our minds we can consolidate and refactor this to make it more efficient :)

so First.

**WaveNative.cs**

```
//callbacks
public delegate void WaveDelegate(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2);
```

**WaveInBuffer.cs / WaveOutBuffer.cs**

```
    internal static void WaveInProc(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveNative.WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2)
    {
        if (uMsg == WaveNative.MM_WIM_DATA)
        {
            try
            {
                GCHandle h = (GCHandle)wavhdr.dwUser;
                WaveInBuffer buf = (WaveInBuffer)h.Target;
                buf.OnCompleted();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
//WaveOutBuffer.cs version
    internal static void WaveOutProc(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveNative.WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2)
    {
        if (uMsg == WaveNative.MM_WOM_DONE)
        {
            try
            {
                GCHandle h = (GCHandle)wavhdr.dwUser;
                WaveOutBuffer buf = (WaveOutBuffer)h.Target;
                buf.OnCompleted();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

**WaveInRecorder.cs / WaveOutRecorder**

```
private WaveNative.WaveDelegate m_BufferProc = new WaveNative.WaveDelegate(WaveInBuffer.WaveInProc);
private WaveNative.WaveDelegate m_BufferProc = new WaveNative.WaveDelegate(WaveOutBuffer.WaveOutProc);
```

In the end they are used for a PInvoke call as follows

```
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutOpen(out IntPtr hWaveOut, int uDeviceID, WaveFormat lpFormat, WaveDelegate dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInOpen(out IntPtr phwi, int uDeviceID, WaveFormat lpFormat, WaveDelegate dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
```

I've consolidated most the other things in the abstract version of WaveBuffer such as the HeaderData, the size of the header, the IntPtr data, a GCHandle HeaderHandle, and HeaderDataHandle. A WaitFor command a OnCompleteCommand, a bool Busy, and a AutoResetEvent. Not sure what it is used for but it's used for, but it is used the same in each file so i just moved it over. Thank you for your patience and reading through this thread.

**EDIT**

sorry for the confusion, i got so wrapped up in finding all this stuff I forgot to ask what i was meaning to ask. Basically teh question is How can I combine these 2 functions that do nearly EXACTLY the same thing? How does this Delegate work from WaveNative such that i can make a new instance in WaveInBuffer/WaveOutBuffer and it means the same thing. I just assumed that I had to always either call the one from the other or just call the base class one. As for m_BufferedProc I'll post the entire code since it is hard for me to understand. Mind you this code I'm posting is not my own. Here it is

```
public class WaveInRecorder : IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr m_WaveIn;
    private WaveInBuffer m_Buffers; // linked list
    private WaveInBuffer m_CurrentBuffer;
    private Thread m_Thread;
    private BufferDoneEventHandler m_DoneProc;
    private bool m_Finished;

    private WaveNative.WaveDelegate m_BufferProc = new WaveNative.WaveDelegate(WaveInBuffer.WaveInProc);

    public static int DeviceCount
    {
        get { return WaveNative.waveInGetNumDevs(); }
    }

    public WaveInRecorder(int device, WaveFormat format, int bufferSize, int bufferCount, BufferDoneEventHandler doneProc)
    {
        m_DoneProc = doneProc;
        WaveInHelper.Try(WaveNative.waveInOpen(out m_WaveIn, device, format, m_BufferProc, 0, WaveNative.CALLBACK_FUNCTION));
        AllocateBuffers(bufferSize, bufferCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferCount; i++)
        {
            SelectNextBuffer();
            m_CurrentBuffer.Record();
        }
        WaveInHelper.Try(WaveNative.waveInStart(m_WaveIn));
        m_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        m_Thread.Start();
    }
    ~WaveInRecorder()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_Thread != null)
            try
            {
                m_Finished = true;
                if (m_WaveIn != IntPtr.Zero)
                    WaveNative.waveInReset(m_WaveIn);
                WaitForAllBuffers();
                m_Thread.Join();
                m_DoneProc = null;
                FreeBuffers();
                if (m_WaveIn != IntPtr.Zero)
                    WaveNative.waveInClose(m_WaveIn);
            }
            finally
            {
                m_Thread = null;
                m_WaveIn = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void ThreadProc()
    {
        while (!m_Finished)
        {
            Advance();
            if (m_DoneProc != null && !m_Finished)
                m_DoneProc(m_CurrentBuffer.Data, m_CurrentBuffer.Size);
            m_CurrentBuffer.Record();
        }
    }
    private void AllocateBuffers(int bufferSize, int bufferCount)
    {
        FreeBuffers();
        if (bufferCount > 0)
        {
            m_Buffers = new WaveInBuffer(m_WaveIn, bufferSize);
            WaveInBuffer Prev = m_Buffers;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < bufferCount; i++)
                {
                    WaveInBuffer Buf = new WaveInBuffer(m_WaveIn, bufferSize);
                    Prev.NextBuffer = Buf;
                    Prev = Buf;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Prev.NextBuffer = m_Buffers;
            }
        }
    }
    private void FreeBuffers()
    {
        m_CurrentBuffer = null;
        if (m_Buffers != null)
        {
            WaveInBuffer First = m_Buffers;
            m_Buffers = null;

            WaveInBuffer Current = First;
            do
            {
                WaveInBuffer Next = Current.NextBuffer;
                Current.Dispose();
                Current = Next;
            } while(Current != First);
        }
    }
    private void Advance()
    {
        SelectNextBuffer();
        m_CurrentBuffer.WaitFor();
    }
    private void SelectNextBuffer()
    {
        m_CurrentBuffer = m_CurrentBuffer == null ? m_Buffers : m_CurrentBuffer.NextBuffer;
    }
    private void WaitForAllBuffers()
    {
        WaveInBuffer Buf = m_Buffers;
        while (Buf.NextBuffer != m_Buffers)
        {
            Buf.WaitFor();
            Buf = Buf.NextBuffer;
        }
    }
```

Mind you that that code is not mine but rather it is Ianier Munoz's. I have a similar version I'm working on, you can browse the code that i extracted from it at http://code.google.com/p/adli/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FAspects%2FCustom%2FAudio

how I use it (not fully implemented is at here)

http://code.google.com/p/adli/source/browse/trunk/Aspects/Panels/Main%20Panels/AudioBrightnessPanel.cs

look at the action listener for my microphone test.

again sorry for the confusion i will try not to post a question without a question again.

Comment: Where are the two `m_BufferProc` fields defined and used?

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is.

Comment: You have `try`/`catch` blocks that do nothing for starters...

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for getting answers to programming questions. You haven't asked a question. You don't have a single question mark in your entire post.

Comment: So sorry about that, i got too wrapped up in the code I forgot to ask. I edited my post. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

well you've got mutually exclusive if blocks which means its pretty easy to merge the 2 together... (i removed the empty catch block because its evil)

```
internal static void WaveProc(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveNative.WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2)
{
    GCHandle h = (GCHandle)wavhdr.dwUser;
    if (uMsg == WaveNative.MM_WIM_DATA)
    {
         WaveInBuffer buf = (WaveInBuffer)h.Target;
         buf.OnCompleted();
    }
    if (uMsg == WaveNative.MM_WOM_DONE)
    {
         WaveOutBuffer buf = (WaveOutBuffer)h.Target;
         buf.OnCompleted();
    }
}
```

`private WaveNative.WaveDelegate m_BufferProc = new WaveNative.WaveDelegate(WaveInBuffer.WaveProc);`

Comment: I like the way you wrote this, but is this really the best approach? (I mean this in an ignorant sense) I'm used to when a person has a delegate that they have an event as well. and then when a condition happens they check for null and then fire that event. Is that not what I should do here? or is this a better approach?